# WebRTC: Event "ontrack" not fires

Tags: webrtc

I'm building a group video chat web app which asking for permissions only when user decided to share his voice/cam, but he should still be able to receive others streams and watching it.

So the scenario is:

1- User (A) starts sending his stream after clicking on "Call" button and allow permissions.

2- Online user (B) should receive his offer and answering it but without giving audio/video permissions.

3- Whenever user (B) clicks on "Call" button he should give permissions and add tracks to his stream, this should fires event `ontrack` on the user (A) side.

**User (A) Offer**

```js
    LocalStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true });

    let peer = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
    
    LocalStream.getTracks().forEach(track => peer.addTrack(track, LocalStream));

    peer.onicecandidate = ({ candidate }) => {
        candidate && socket.emit('candidated', userId, candidate);
    }
    peer.ontrack = (e) => {
        console.log(e); // This doesn't fires
    }
    peer.createOffer()
        .then(offer => peer.setLocalDescription(offer))
        .then(() => socket.emit('send-offer', userId, peer.localDescription));
```

**User (B) answering offer**

```js
    let peer = new RTCPeerConnection(config);

    peer.onicecandidate = ({ candidate }) => {
        candidate && socket.emit('candidated', userId, candidate);
    }
    peer.ontrack = (e) => {
        console.log(e); // This fires
    }
    peer.setRemoteDescription(offer)
        .then(() => peer.createAnswer())
        .then((answer) => peer.setLocalDescription(answer))
        .then(() => socket.emit('send-answer', userId, peer.localDescription));
```

**Later: User (B) Starts call and adding his tracks**

```js
   // peer = User (A) Peer Connection
   LocalStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true });
   LocalStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
      peer.addTrack(track, LocalStream);
   });
```

The problem is that:
Event `ontrack` never fired on the user (A) side.